# Factorial function in Python, why does i have to range from 1 to k+1?

Tags: python

I have the following code for calculating the factorial of a natural number k:

```
def Fac(k):

    assert k>=0, "Please only insert a non-negative integer k"

    Fac=1

    for i in range(1,k+1):
        Fac*=i

    return Fac

print(Fac(k))
```

I don't think this is the optimal way to define the factorial function, but that's not the point. If you run the code, and insert a non-negative integer k in "print(Fac(k))", then you get the correct answer. My problem is: why does i have to range from 1 to k+1? In my head, if k is, say 4, then k+1=5, so i would have to range from 1 to 5, and if you look at the code the last multiplication would be by 5, and that doesn't make sense. Can anyone elaborate on this? Or am I really missing something obvious?

At the moment I don't have an answer.

Thanks

Comment: This way is very optimal. In any case... the end of a `range` is noninclusive, so the last multiplication would by by `4` not by `5`

Comment: As to "why", this might help: [by Djkstra](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)

Answer (score 2):

`range(1,5)` means the sequence of 1, 2, 3, 4. The end of range is **not** included in results. So to get all numbers from 1 to k (including k) you need to use `range(1, k+1)`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't know that, but very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Lists in python, and thus `range`, are zero-indexed. So `range` starts at 0 by default. e.g. `list(range(5))` gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Because of that, you'd be multiplying `0 * 1 * 2...`,  which will always give 0. This is why you specify that your range should start at 1. i.e. `range(1,k+1)`

Answer (score 1):

range(n) is zero based and produces 0, 1, 2, ... n-1. For example:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

produces

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Aha, this is really helpful! It makes sense now. I did not know that the range function starts at zero.

Answer (score 0):

The `Python` function `range` starts at `0` and ends at the second input minus one. You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp). That means that `range(3)` loops through `0, 1, 2` and `range(1, 5)` loops through `1, 2, 3, 4`.